# Java class constructor this.id = id or this.setId(id)

Tags: java, android, class, php-7

In Android Studio I created a Person.java class. I used Generate to create getters and setters and also a constructor.

This is my Person.java class:

```
public class Person {
private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;

    public User(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setId(int Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Can/should I change the constructor to this:

```
public Person(int Id, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    this.setId(Id);
    this.setFirstName(firstName);
    this.setLastName(lastName);
    this.setEmail(email);
}
```

What will be better, the one auto generated or the one I changed to? Will it have some improvement at runtime?

I got same question for PHP (7.4) classes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the class were to be designed as [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), one would only have the choice of `this.id = id;`. As-is, it is a matter of style.

Comment: @Turing85 so except for that, there will no performance problems? Bc on the latter it uses another method to assign the value. In the first it directly uses this.id = id

Comment: The JIT compiler will most probably inline the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java compiler in general optimizes a lot of stuff so in the end the code probably gets converted to the second example anyways because method calls are often worse than just setting a value directly.

In your example it really doesn't make a difference, I would just keep the first one because you can just keep it as it was generated. Even if the second option performs better the benefit is way too small to be noticed.

The only reason to really call setters in constructors is if they have logic inside them, in your case you could check if the email is a real email. Then it would be better to call `setEmail(email)` in the constructor as the method contains logic that shouldn't be put inside of the constructor (and also having a check in the constructor and in the setter would be unnecessary code duplication)

As your doing Android Programming you could check out Kotlin too which would just look like this:

```
data class User(val id:Int, var firstName:String, var lastName:String, var email:String)
```

**That replaces the whole class that you wrote**, you don't need setters as you can optionally define them when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Setter methods are generally used when we need to modify the value of a field. Whereas we are initializing the values of these fields in the constructor based on the parameters provided while the object creation. So I guess its a better practice when we do this.id = id

Answer (score 0):

It depends if your setters do anything like validation. Maybe you want to validate the `id` is positive or that the `email` address is valid. In these cases there are 2 places you can put the validation logic, either in the constructor or in the setters. In the constructor makes sense if the class is immutable but in the setters makes sense if not, in which case it make sense to call the setters from the constructors.